# What is the replacement for 'require_once' in PHP for Magento2 to resolve CodeSniffer test issue in Magento store?

Tags: php, magento, magento2, phpcodesniffer

I'm a beginner at PHP and Magento have developed a Magento2 extension and used this line code in it:

```
require_once '/../knownuserv3/KnownUser.php';
```

But when I tried to put my extension in Magento Store, I got a series of test failure from Code Sniffer, which I solved all but for this one couldn't find any solution until now.
knownuser is a class in another library includes a static method which I need to call it.
this is the error text from Code Sniffer:
[image]

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html I'm not familiar with magento but it sounds like you can use DI to inject the class you need to use

Comment: But it's a static method, I don't want an instance of the type I just need the type.

Comment: What happens if you put a use statement in the file ?

Comment: I did it, but it can't find the file if you don't use 'require', because it's in a third party library.